# How to check if the form opened has a parent form

Tags: asp.net

I am using thickbox to display the list of data, but when the session timeout occurs, and user try to open the thickbox by clicking a link, the thickbox gets open and the login page starts loading in the thickbox it self. So, is there any way where we can check if the form (thickbox) has a parent form ? or a javascript code like:

```
if(document.hasParent)
{
 TB_CLOSE();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like below:

```
if (self == parent){
 //this is parent
}
```

Or otherway:

```
if (self != parent){
 //this is not parent
}
```